# My Bigquery job succesfully in terraform but not done in cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I created a job to run query in cloud in terraform and it run succesfully but job not done in clouds.
**biquery.tf**

```
resource "google_bigquery_job" "user_data_job" {
  job_id     = "job_query_${random_id.random_job_id.hex}"
  location = "US"


labels = {
    "job_type" ="create_table"
  }
  query {
    query = "CREATE TABLE myproject.shop45_dataset.user_data AS SELECT first_name, last_name, email,FROM myporject.shop45_dataset.shop_data"

    destination_table {
      project_id = google_bigquery_table.shop_table.project
      dataset_id = google_bigquery_table.shop_table.dataset_id
      table_id   = google_bigquery_table.shop_table.table_id
    }
   allow_large_results = true
    flatten_results = true

  }
  depends_on = [
    google_bigquery_job.import_job
  ]
}
```

also i try different sql query

```
CREATE TABLE `user_data` AS SELECT first_name, last_name, email, FROM ${google_bigquery_table.shop_table.table_id}"
```

I want to create a table from shop_table table

My cloud log.

```
job_type: "create_table"
}
query: {
createDisposition: "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"
defaultDataset: {0}
destinationTable: {3}
query: "CREATE TABLE t-12-vm.shop45_dataset.user_data AS SELECT first_name, last_name, email,FROM t-12-vm.shop45_dataset.shop_data"
queryPriority: "QUERY_INTERACTIVE"
statementType: "QUERY_STATEMENT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED"
writeDisposition: "WRITE_EMPTY"
}
}
jobName: {3}
jobStatistics: {3}
jobStatus: {
additionalErrors: [1]
error: {
code: 11
message: "Cannot set destination table in jobs with DDL statements"
}
state: "DONE"
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: If you run terraform plan before does it show you that the BQ job will be ran? Also does your terraform have the right permissions to run the job?

Comment: In addition to @Beembo 's comment, can you also provide the actual error message you got from cloud logging?

Comment: my clouds log-
`job_type: "create_table"
}
query: {
createDisposition: "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"
defaultDataset: {0}
destinationTable: {3}
query: "CREATE TABLE t-12-vm.shop45_dataset.user_data AS SELECT first_name, last_name, email,FROM t-12-vm.shop45_dataset.shop_data"
queryPriority: "QUERY_INTERACTIVE"
statementType: "QUERY_STATEMENT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED"
writeDisposition: "WRITE_EMPTY"
}
}
jobName: {3}
jobStatistics: {3}
jobStatus: {
additionalErrors: [1]
error: {
code: 11
message: "Cannot set destination table in jobs with DDL statements"
}
state: "DONE"
}
}
}
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the `destination_table` property.  It's conflicting with the query.

Alternatively, remove the `CREATE TABLE AS` from `query` and allow the results to land in the destination table and manage the DDL part explicitly.